# Compile Vim with Python support on OS X

Tags: python, macos, vim, compilation

I start in the Vim `src` directory

```
$ pwd
~/vim/src
$ ./configure \
> --prefix=$HOME/Applications/vim-compiled \
> --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
> --enable-pythoninterp=yes \
> --with-python-config-dir=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config
$ make
```

At the end of `make`, I get the following error

```
ld: warning: in /Library/Frameworks//Python.framework/Python, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
Undefined symbols:
<very long list of Undefined symbols>
...
...
...
<very long list of Undefined symbols>
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [vim] Error 1
```

What's causing the error? I've found answers in similar questions that advise using MacPorts, Homebrew, or MacVim. I don't want to use any of those. Is there some other way around?

**UPDATE**: This is the output listing the `Undefined symbols` http://pastebin.com/ggV87ReF

Comment: Why not MacPorts/Homebrew/MacVim? MacVim is quite possibly the most straightforward solution.

Comment: @romainl, I don't want MacVim because I prefer to work in the Terminal. I don't want MacPorts/Homebrew because my Python installation is already set up using the installer from Python.org. Or to put it simply, I'm trying to keep my installations clean.

Comment: There is a CLI Vim executable in MacVim's application bundle that will work with any Python/Ruby you have on your Mac without needing to tweak/update anything. That's what I use since 10 months and I never had to recompile Vim despite changing active Python/Ruby versions numerous times.

Comment: You really should install macvim with homebrew. Just alias it to vim. "alias vim='mvim -v'" will make it behave how you would expect.

Comment: @romainl, I downloaded the MacVim source, tried to compile with Python support, and I still get the same architecture related errors. So I replaced the 32-bit Python 2.7.2 with the 64-bit version and things went fine from then on. Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy to learn that you solved your problem but, as I said, you didn't need to compile anything: MacVim.app comes bundled with a CLI Vim (.../MacVim.app/Content/MacOS/vim) that will work with any version present or future of Python already present on your machine. Just download the .app, add an alias to your `~/.profile` and you are set.

Comment: @romaini, Why do you say "*will work with any version present or future of Python already present on your machine*"?  When I look at the version info for the CLI Vim inside MacVim.app, I get: `+python`, `-python3`, so for example jedi/vim won't give me any parameter info when I type `print(` when using MacVim.  I believe that's because MacVim and its Vim are associated with a python2.x version, and I also believe it is not possible to associate MacVim with a python3.x version because of the `-python3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried upgrading to the OSX 32-bit/64-bit version of Python 2.7.**2**? I'm not sure if there was a specific 64-bit version of 2.7, and that might be causing problems.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I've installed MacVim on 10.6.8 using the following command 
`./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-perlinterp=yes --enable-pythoninterp=yes --with-features=huge --with-python-config-dir=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6`

`sudo make`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Homebrew recipe for vim (or macvim) and modify it if necessary.  https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The link you provided doesn't have any Python reference to it.

Comment: See [this part](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/macvim.rb#L30) of the MacVim recipe for Python-specific tweaks.

Comment: Thanks @romainl, I tried using the `./configure` options but I still get the same error. I think it's got something to do with `missing required architecture x86_64 in file`

Comment: Yes, it's rather obvious. But if your Python works as is I don't know what you could do to it. Is your machine running in 64 bit or in 32 bit? Is your Python compiled as 64 bit or as 32 bit? Is it the default Python provided by Apple (I think yes)? Did you try installing another Python (via MacPorts or some other means)?